# Detect Microphone State Change on Android to detect audio recording

Tags: android, audio, detection, record, broadcast

I was trying to make an Android APP whose main function is to detect

if other  android APPs are recording voice using Microphone. So far, I learned

that getRecordingState() from AudioRecord class can be used to get the state

of whether microphone is recording or not... but I need something like a broadcast

so I can catch the intent while the state of microphone starts to record voice...

any idea ?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018927/check-if-android-mic-is-being-used-by-another-app

I think this problem is very similar to mine...but still...no answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRecordingState()` returns the state for the particular `AudioRecord` instance that you call the method on. It doesn't give you some global state for all recorders.

There's currently no API available for applications to check globally whether there's ongoing recording from the microphone. The `AudioFlinger` has that information (though not about *which* specific application that is doing the recording), but the only way for you to get hold of it would be to modify Android itself and run your own custom Android version.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AudioManager.isMicrophoneMute()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMicrophoneMute()