# Android - How to check Microphone is currently being used by some other application

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

I am having a soundrecorder application code, Based upon the microphone state. I want to display the status like, If microphone is already used by some other application, To display the status like microphone is already in use else recording... like that, so i used the below code to get the microphone state in recorder.getRecordingState() but it always returning 1, even though i am in call or in idle. Help me some code to get the microphone state. Thanks in advance.

```
 int[] mSampleRates = new int[]{8000, 11025, 22050, 44100};

    for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
        for (short audioFormat : new short[]{AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT}) {
            for (short channelConfig : new short[]{AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO}) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                            + channelConfig);
                    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
        if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                        // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                        AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                        if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {

                            Log.i("", "Recorder intialised " + recorder.getRecordingState() + "  " + recorder.getState() + "   ");
                            return recorder;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

        return null;
```

Comment: Look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018927/check-if-android-mic-is-being-used-by-another-app

Comment: Thanks sunny, I dont have idea about HAL layer, Can you please help me to get the status from the application level

Answer (score 2):

Hi i Found the partial answer, If the microphone is used by phone application (CALL) we can get the mode (2 = in call mode , 0 = normal mode). If the microphone is used by some other application don,t know how to find. cheers

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.getMode();
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [`getRecordingState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#getRecordingState()), this method only checks if the state have been initialized for your current instance. If you want to know if the microphone is currently used for a call, you should use [`AudioManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getMode()).

Comment: Thanks valentin, Can you please share some sample code to get it.

Comment: I don't have sample code ready for this, as this was just from a research on the reference. Sorry.